# E. Coli growth inhibited in Powdered Honey

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I ran into problem with my method validation since the *E. Coli* that I've spiked into my Honey Powder sample can't grow in the media. The media I've used is Merck CCA (Chromogenic Coliform Agar). I've also used the MPN method (3 tubes) using LST Broth with the same result.

Really appreciate if someone Can  lead me into why would this happen and give any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to grow *E. coli* in the presence of honey, right?

This migth be the problem as honey inhibits bacterial grow. See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/15857217/). Therefore, it also doesn't matter which medium you are using.